# Unable to encode value in phoenix (elixir) - Can't parse JSON request with an array

Tags: mongodb, elixir

I'm running phoenix with ecto MongoDB and have a model with an array of maps, that phoenix can't parse and save.

This is the structure of the request that I'm sending to the server:

```
{
  id: "",
  name: "",
  items: [
    { name: "item 1" },
    { name: "item 2" }
    ...
  ]
  ...
}
```

**Edit: I'm sending the data using jQuery**

```
$.post("/api/v1/notes/update.json", {
  id: note.id,
  note: note
}, (data) => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

But what I'm receiving is:

```
{
  id: "",
  name: "",
  items: {
      "0": { name: "item 1" },
       "1": { name: "item 2" }
       ...
    }
  ...
}
```

This is how I defined the array field in the model. But it seems that it accept just a map.

```
field :items, {:array, :map}, default: []
```

The model item.ex

```
@primary_key {:id, :binary_id, autogenerate: true}
schema "notes" do
  field :name, :string, default: ""
  field :items, {:array, :map}, default: []
  field :created, Ecto.DateTime

  timestamps
end

@required_fields ~w(name)
@optional_fields [:items, created]

def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do

  struct
  |> cast(params, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
end
```

The controller action:

```
item = Repo.get!(Item, id)
changeset = Item.changeset(item, item_params)

case Repo.update(changeset) do
  {:ok, item} ->
    conn
    |> send_resp(201, "success")
  {:error, changeset} ->
    conn
    |> put_status(:unprocessable_entity)
    |> render(Plans.ErrorJSON, "error.json", changeset: changeset)
end
```

I also tried to build a new map with the items array, but didn't succeed.

```
itms = []
Enum.map(items, fn(item) ->
  Itms = List.insert_at(items, List.last(items), item)  
end)
```

**Edit:**
This is the error I'm getting using Poison:

```
Poison.EncodeError) unable to encode value: {:items, "is invalid"}
(poison) lib/poison/encoder.ex:354: Poison.Encoder.Any.encode/2
(poison) lib/poison/encoder.ex:232: anonymous fn/3 in Poison.Encoder.List.encode/3
```

How can I parse and save JSON objects to MongoDB that includes arrays?

Comment: How are you "sending to the server"? And where are you "receiving" that structure from?

Comment: Have you tried using something like `Poison`? You can call `Poison.decode` or `Poison.encode`

Comment: @Dogbert I'm sending the data using jQuery `$.post`

Comment: @ThetraNetwork can you add the exact line(s) that call `$.post` to the question? I believe jQuery is sending them as URL parameters instead of JSON which do not encode arrays in a way that Phoenix can decode into lists.

Comment: @HarrisonLucas yes, I was getting this error: 
`
Poison.EncodeError) unable to encode value: {:items, "is invalid"}
(poison) lib/poison/encoder.ex:354: Poison.Encoder.Any.encode/2
(poison) lib/poison/encoder.ex:232: anonymous fn/3 in Poison.Encoder.List.encode/3
`

Comment: @Dogbert yes, I it looks like jQuery causing this by adding a key number to the array

Comment: @ThetraNetwork Can you post the code for the controller action which is returning the JSON in the first snippet of the question?

Comment: @Dogbert yes, I added it, thanks, and I think this is a problem on the client side

Comment: @ThetraNetwork the controller action code you posted does not send `item` to `conn` so I'm not sure how you're even getting the JSON object you said you are getting in `(data) => console.log(data)`.

Comment: @ThetraNetwork my guess is that you need to pass the data through `JSON.stringify` in the client side code before sending it via `$.post` and then decode using `Poison.decode` but I cannot suggest anything more concrete than that as I cannot follow the code and response snippets you've posted.